# Merge or c*rbind a list of table results in a data.frame & adding missing values

Tags: r, list, merge

My google technique was not successful today, so I ask a new question:

I have a matrix of values `c(0, 2, 3)`:

```
> a
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2  2
2  2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2  2
3  0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0  2
4  0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0  2
5  2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2  2
6  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
7  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
8  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
9  2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2  2
10 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
```

I calculate for each row the occurence of these values using `apply`

```
res <- apply(a, 1, table)
res[1:3]
[[1]]

2 3 
6 4 

[[2]]

2 3 
6 4 

[[3]]

0 2 
2 8
```

Now I try to merge the list to one data.frame by filling up the missing values in some slots by `0` or `NA` and optionally with the name. My goal is a simple function using `do.call` or something like `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), res)`. But both approaches are not working.

Expected output would be:

```
final[1:3, ]
     0 2 3
[1,] 0 6 4
[2,] 0 6 0
[3,] 2 8 8
```

and the data:

```
structure(list(`1` = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `2` = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `3` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), `4` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `5` = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2), `6` = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2), `7` = c(3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2), `8` = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
2), `9` = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `10` = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: I think you should store this as a matrix. Then you can just use `table(row(a), as.matrix(a))`

Comment: @Frank Most elegant solution, by far. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `smartbind` from `gtools` package:

```
library(gtools)
do.call(smartbind, c(apply(a, 1, table), fill = 0)) # fill by 0's, default is NA
#    2 3 0
#1   6 4 0
#2   6 4 0
#3   8 0 2
#4   ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't now the function so far.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative would be to define full levels before calling table:

```
res <- apply(a, 1, function(x){x<-factor(x ,levels=c(0,2,3)) ; table(x) } )
as.data.frame(t(res))
#      0  2 3
#[1,] 0  6 4
#[2,] 0  6 4
#[3,] 2  8 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `base R`

```
table(rep(1:nrow(a), ncol(a)), unlist(a))
#      0  2  3
#  1   0  6  4
#  2   0  6  4
#  3   2  8  0
#  4   2  8  0
#  5   0  6  4
#  6   0 10  0
#  7   0 10  0
#  8   0 10  0
#  9   0  6  4
#  10  0 10  0
```